# Why can't I play multiplayer in Age of Mythology?

Tags: age-of-mythology

I just dug up one my my favorite games, Age of Mythology, and I can't get the online multiplayer to work. It just pops up with a blank message and then returns me to the log-in screen.

Searching Microsoft's site just results in a bunch of missing pages.

Does anybody know if online multiplayer is still supported, or if Microsoft has discontinued it?

Comment: This question is offtopic, because it is essentially a shopping recommendation.

Comment: This is not a shopping recommendation.

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta Here's a [StackExchange blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) on what is typically  meant by "shopping recommendation". What we care about is that it fundamentally doesn't work well with the Q&A format, not that someone is using the information in the question to make a determination of whether or not to purchase something. But even more so in this case, cstack said he already owns the game, so even that doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AoM online multiplayer IS still up and running, although <200 people are actually on it.

The password reset utility in-game is broken, but you can go to the [Windows Live Login Page](http://login.live.com) and reset it from there. Your email is [AoM username]@eso.com.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anything about the servers being taken down. [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/331406) is a Microsoft support page for AoM multiplayer. You might also check [PortForward](http://portforward.com/) to make sure you have your ports set up correctly for the game.